# What is the size of mallocs internal buffer

Tags: c, malloc

I'm benchmarking my implementation of `gc_malloc` against the Windows implementation of `malloc`. The way I understand it, `malloc` uses an internal buffer to give memory so it doesn't need to call `mmap` (or the like) so often.

When the buffer my allocator (`gc_malloc`) uses is of size `4096`, I lose by 5x to `malloc`, but when it's `32768` I get equal timing to the system `malloc`. Likewise, increasing that value causes me to win more against system `malloc`.

What's the approximate size of the buffer reserved by `malloc` before it calls `mmap` again?

Comment: In recent versions of the (release, non-debug) Visual C++ C Runtime (CRT), `malloc` basically just calls `HeapAlloc`.  The behavior of `HeapAlloc` depends on the version of the operating system on which you are running your program (the heap is improved every release).  Note that maximum performance is not the only design goal of the Windows heap.  Security (e.g., resilience during buffer overruns) is also extremely important.

Comment: Using `gcov` I found my benchmark was making `34246` calls to `mmap` (msys2) in my code for some 20 million allocations. Could it be `mmap` that's *really slow*, such that `34k` calls would take 20 seconds, or my allocator?

Comment: `34246` msys2 `mmap` calls takes 18.9 seconds, so I confirm `mmap` to being very slow on msys2.

Comment: @kvanberendonck if you're going to write your own allocator on windows I would suggest basing it on `HeapAlloc` or if you're feeling really insane `VirtualAlloc`

Comment: cheers! Now I've confirmed the msys2 emulation to be slow, it just means I have to #ifdef everywhere to insert the appropriate windows calls.

Comment: Rather than doing `#ifdef` everywhere, why not just put ONE `#ifdef` at the beginning of the file to replace `mmap` with a macro which calls an inline function using the appropriate windows calls in place of it? This way you avoid horribly uglifying your code.

Comment: And you can get the size of the allocated buffer using HeapSize.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured it out. When I changed to using `VirtualAlloc` I was getting speeds three times as fast as `malloc` on all block sizes. Research indicates that `malloc` just calls HeapAlloc.